# Elements overlap in vertical flexbox column layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a layout single-column css layout, where each of the elements in the column is a `<section>` tag, and they have `min-height: 60vh` configured.
This works well until I make the whole layout a flexbox with direction column:
When the content of a section is vertically larger than 60vh (On sufficiently small screens)  then elements overlap - their height is only 60vh.

Minimal example html:

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="box">
      some content
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="box">
      some content
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="box">
      some content
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Minimal example css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

section {
  min-height: 60vh;
  --grad-col: red;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  --grad-col: red;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  --grad-col: blue;
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  --grad-col: orange;
}

.box {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: color-mix(in srgb, transparent 50%, var(--grad-col));
}
```

[image: browser rendered output]

How can I prevent this, without changing the flex-layout, and while still guaranteeing that each element is at least 60vh high?

https://codepen.io/rastaiari/pen/BaMvber

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D I added a minimal code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to section `flex: none;`

The item is sized according to its width and height properties. It is fully inflexible: it neither shrinks nor grows in relation to the flex container. This is equivalent to setting `flex: 0 0 auto`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-shrink:0;` to keep the sections from collapsing

```
section {
  min-height: 60vh;
  flex-shrink:0;
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  --grad-col: red;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, var(--grad-col) 0, transparent 1px, transparent 0, transparent 50%);
}
```